# How to change the code template/layout in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have started to learn C#, so I have started to use VS Code as my editor and have also installed dotnet framework with it.

The problem is that when I create a new file, my file has a completely different code setup/layout/template, unlike the one that I had seen in a video, and I was wondering if I could change that default template, to the one in the video, so that it automatically loads in when I create a new C# file.

I tried to search through the VS settings and preferences, googling it, but can't seem to find this specific answer.

Currently when I create a new file I get such looking code:
[look of the code that I get when I create the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNjrW.png)

but I am looking to find this type of code, so that I can follow up with the tutorial that I am following:

[look of code that I want to get when I create the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyXYT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can set template by following below steps[image]